# Webpack hot module replacement with Ember app

Tags: ember.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying run webpack HMR with ember app. I haven not found any ember specific hot loader for ember yet. Never mind, my problem is that only css changes are hot loaded without refresh. 
When I change java file, I can see in a console this:

`[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...`

`[WDS] App hot update...`

`[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...`

`[HMR] Updated modules:`

`[HMR]  - 541`

`[HMR] App is up to date.`

... so it seems HMR is working. Also I am able to find an updated module source code in console management but the changes are not visible on the web page I cant found out why.

Maybe it is because module is physically updated in a browser memory, but not in ember environment.

Any ideas how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/` link? If not, you need to include script `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` to have working HMR.